# Passing data through Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, eclipse-adt

I'm currently trying to program an app which requires the user to key in their name. This is the "Login" page.

public class Login extends Activity
{

```
EditText username;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.MainActivity");

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("name", username.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(extras);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

protected void onDestroy() {        
    super.onDestroy();
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveAsPreferences();
}

protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    saveAsPreferences();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    retrievePreferences();
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    retrievePreferences();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    saveAsPreferences();
}
public void saveAsPreferences() 
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Name = username.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("name", Name);
    editor.commit();
}
public void retrievePreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs.contains("name"))
    {
        String Name = prefs.getString("name", "");
        username.setText(Name);
    }
}
```

}

and this is my Result page

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String Name = bundle.getString("name");
    TextView welcomeUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);
    welcomeUser.setText("Hello " + Name + "!");
```

}

why isn't my codes working? Thanks!
Note: I've linked the pages correctly before I start on passing data.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order like in your `Login Activity`

```
setContentView(R.layout.login);
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
```

First you need to `setContentView(..)` then reference `Views`.

Comment: what do you mean by Views?

Comment: @user3774763 Your **EditText**, **TextView** and so on... it's just kind of **Views**.

Comment: you mean import? i did import, just that i didnt show that part

Answer (score 0):

do in this way . in your login class don't use Bundle . use intent.putExtra("name",username);  and then in your main activity class . getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); this will return the username and define your Edittext aftert setContentView

Comment: intent.putExtra is invalid argument due to cause username is in EditText, it is also invalid for username.getText().ToString() cause both are strings

Comment: it cant be wrong argument because intent.putExtra has 2 string arguments first "name" second username.getText().toString()

Comment: The method putExtras(Intent) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, String) that's the error